# Get row of NSPopUpButton in view based NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, nstableview

I have a view based table view with one row containing NSPopupButtons. When the user changes the popUpButton I need to get get the table row in which this popUpButton is contained.

I first expected to get the row with

```
NSInteger clickedRow = [tableView rowForView: ((NSPopUpButton*) sender)];
```

But the sender of the action always is a `NSMenuItem` object not the `NSPopUpButton`. `NSMenuItem` however is not a view so I cannot use `rowForView` with that.

Currently my IBAction looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)changedPopUp:(id)sender {
    NSMenuItem* selectedMenuItem = ((NSMenuItem*) sender);
    NSPopUpButton* popupButton = (NSPopUpButton*)[selectedMenuItem view];
    NSInteger clickedRow = [tableView rowForView:popupButton];
    //[...]
}
```

But the view property is not set automatically and I find it quite inconvenient to set it manually for every NSMenuItem.

Is there no easy way to get the table row?

Answer (score 1):

Don't set an action and target for each `NSMenuItem`. Set the action and target for the `NSPopupButton` instead. Then, `sender` will be the `NSPopupButton` instance and you can use `rowForView`.

The drawback is of course that you cannot have different actions for different menu items.